# (Citrix) Printers not updating on switching Wyse

Tags: windows, printing, citrix, xendesktop, wyse

At our company we are using Wyses connected to XenDesktop. People are changing working places all the time.

What are the best solutions so that Printers are always updated correctly if user switches working place?

We have outsourced our IT, and I have problems believing there is no good solution for this by Citrix.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get the scenario. Feel free to add:

- What printer system do you use? (it is different having local printers or a Windows Print Server, for example)
- What do you want to happen? (print to the closest printer, give the user a choice?)

Not having the info, I can go with generic information!

Check the [Citrix Tech Zone on printing](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/tech-zone/design/design-decisions/baseline-printing-design.html):

1. If you're using network printers, you'll probably looking for Citrix Universal Print Server Routing ("Use if non-Windows endpoint device and printer are on the same high-speed, low-latency network as the Windows Print Server").

[image: Citrix Universal Print Server Routing]

2. If you're using local printers, you'll probably be looking for Client Device Routing and, if using it with Citrix Universal Printer Driver, you need to [configure Wyse for Citrix Universal Printer Driver](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/wyse-5470-aio/thinos9.0_ag/configure-the-citrix-upd-printer?guid=guid-94d0d082-2976-4506-824a-74936381d4e8&lang=en-us).

[image: Client Device Routing]

The [docs on printing](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-virtual-apps-desktops/printing.html) and the [Citrix Printing Quick Start Guide](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX227534) are also useful.

At my company, we have a pool of network printers, and to finalize the print job, we use a proximity card to authenticate in the printer (in this case, the "intelligence" is on the printer software). Not having this kind of service, you might, and considering you've Dell Wyse, in the worst case, need a script to match the thin client to the office zone (and the printers in it).